# Setting UserAccount/Properties/Environment and UserAccount/Properties/Sessions with Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, user-accounts, wmic

I just wrote a batch file to create windows users with some default properties.
Mostly using `net user` and `net localgroup`.

```
@echo off 
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," %%a in (usuarios.csv) do (
  echo === Aniadiendo y configurando Usuario %%a ===
  net user %%a somePassword /add ^
  /fullname:"%%b" /comment:"%%c" ^
  /logonpasswordchg:no ^
  /expires:never ^
  /passwordchg:no 
  net localgroup someGroup %%a /add
```

However, looking around for how to set up a never expiring password I found that I could use `wmic useraccount` to set up some properties using a kind of structured query language.

```
wmic useraccount WHERE "Name='%%a'" set PasswordExpires=false
```

Seems to me like a more powerful way to set up properties, but I cannot find good documentation with my googles. It almost feels like MS don't want me to know how to script for their system. But that does not sound like them, does it?

Anyway, I want to be able to script the properties under [UserAccount Properties: Environment Tab](https://forsenergy.com/en-us/tsuserex/html/4cb236b2-2c8b-424e-a551-738bb9a47847.htm), particularly `Starting Program` and `Start in`. But I guess once I know how or where could I find this info I'll be able to set `client devices` as well.

Any info on how to script for the settings under [UserAccount Properties:Sessions](https://forsenergy.com/en-us/tsuserex/html/4d02843f-473a-44b4-8f02-df1e375854a3.htm) would be appreciated as well, I think knowing how to set one will solve the other one.

I assume `wmic` should be able to do it but for the life of me I have not been able to find out how for the past few days.